# expand/collapse listener for netbeans outline

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, listener, jtreetable

I am using [`org.netbeans.swing.outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/index.html?org/netbeans/swing/outline/DefaultOutlineModel.html)

How can I setup an expand/collapse Listener to the generated Tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`addTreeExpansionListener()`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/TreePathSupport.html#addTreeExpansionListener%28javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionListener%29) method of [`TreePathSupport`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/TreePathSupport.html) can add a conventional `javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionListener`.

Addendum: For example, given an instance named `outline`, the following anonymous listener will print the affected path:

```
TreePathSupport tps = outlineModel.getTreePathSupport();
tps.addTreeExpansionListener(new TreeExpansionListener() {

    @Override
    public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPath());
    }

    @Override
    public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPath());
    }
});
```

Comment: I was always trying to make a new `TreePathSupport` and not get it from the `outlineModel`... thanks for the help :D

Comment: Truth be told: I did the same thing. :-)